# How to block access to content controls - open xml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I'm reading content control from docx by its tag. And I want to block acces to it (user will not be able to edit content). How can I do that?
Here is my code for getting control by its tag name from docx document:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocTarget = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFilePath, true))
{
      MainDocumentPart mainPartSource = wordDocSource.MainDocumentPart;
      SdtBlock sdtBlock = mainPartSource.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "myTagName").SingleOrDefault();

      // rest of my code (editing inner text) 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a `Lock` (`<w:lock>`) element in the `SdtProperties`-element - that will make the content read-only. For example this defines a plain text content control containing the text 'hello' which appears read-only when editing the document in Word:

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
        <w:sdt>
            <w:sdtPr>
                <w:lock w:val="contentLocked" />
                <w:text />
            </w:sdtPr>
            <w:sdtContent>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>hello</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:sdtContent>
        </w:sdt>
  ...
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

In code you can use something like this to add the lock:

```
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\test.docx", true))
{
    SdtBlock sdtBlock = 
        document
        .MainDocumentPart
        .Document
        .Body
        .Descendants<SdtBlock>()
        .Where(b => b.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "myTagName")
        .SingleOrDefault();

    var contentLock = new Lock { Val = LockingValues.SdtContentLocked };
    sdtBlock.SdtProperties.AppendChild(contentLock);
}
```

I find it usefull to start with a Word-document and then use OpenXML Productivity Tool to see the xml produced by Word.

Comment: Thanks! it works great :) And I add that sdtBlock.SdtProperties.RemoveAllChildren<Lock>(); will unblock SdtBlock.